# JTable is resizing my column widths

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtree, jtreetable

I have created a `JTreeTable` where the `TreeCellRenderer` is a `JTable`. This allows me to have different `TableColumnModel`s for each row. Siblings of the `JTree` share a `TableColumnModel`. It works great. I can select a row and show a different set of columns without actually changing the the data in the other rows even at different levels.

I have a problem though where when select a different row the JTable is changing my `TableColumn`s width and setting it to the preferred size. So the effect is that dragging the width of one column and then selecting a different row set it back to the preferred size.

I have tried a number of things to fix this, including adding a `TableColumnModelListener` and when I change the width I set the preferred size of the column. This doesn't work because the JTable is setting the preferred size to 15 after I change it.

I have traced the code back to what is causing this. It is the `JTable.doLayout()` method causing my grief. That method is calling the private method `setWidthsFromPreferredWidths(...)`. This method is what is setting my TableColumn widths.

I tried overriding the `doLayout()` method since it is public but I could not make the call to `super.doLayout()` when I am already overriding the method. Not calling that causes some very weird UI issues as you could imagine. I also tried casting `this` to the superclass of `JTable` which is `JComponent` but I end up with a stack overflow error. This does not feel like the right solution here anyway.

What I think is happening is that because my `JTable` is inside of a panel as the renderer of a tree cell instead of inside of a scrollpane, that something is going wrong with the layout.I don't know for sure though. Below is the code inside of the private method I referenced above:

```
private void setWidthsFromPreferredWidths(final boolean inverse) {
    int totalWidth     = getWidth();
    int totalPreferred = getPreferredSize().width;
    int target = !inverse ? totalWidth : totalPreferred;

    final TableColumnModel cm = columnModel;
    Resizable3 r = new Resizable3() {
        public int  getElementCount()      { return cm.getColumnCount(); }
        public int  getLowerBoundAt(int i) { return cm.getColumn(i).getMinWidth(); }
        public int  getUpperBoundAt(int i) { return cm.getColumn(i).getMaxWidth(); }
        public int  getMidPointAt(int i)  {
            if (!inverse) {
                return cm.getColumn(i).getPreferredWidth();
            }
            else {
                return cm.getColumn(i).getWidth();
            }
        }
        public void setSizeAt(int s, int i) {
            if (!inverse) {
                cm.getColumn(i).setWidth(s);
            }
            else {
                cm.getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(s);
            }
        }
    };

    adjustSizes(target, r, inverse);
}
```

Looking at the code, I think what's happening is that the `getWidth()` method is causing the JTable to want to resize the columns to the preferredsize because it thinks it doesn't have enough room. I tried just copy pasting this method locally but since there are private methods involved and it kept getting deeper and deeper I stopped that. The intention was to try to debug why it is choose to adjust the width. If I can address the root cause, that may be the best solution for this.

The `JTree` itself is inside of `JScrollPane`. The `JTableHeader` is set to the `ViewPortColumnHeaderView`. Below are 2 images where I am selecting different rows. Ignore the header alignment, I already have a solution for that just did not implement it entirely yet.

[image: JTreeTable-Level1]
[image: JTreeTable-Level2]

Any thoughts on the problem would be greatly appreciated. Also happy to post any code you think might be useful if you think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of modifications and investigation, It was due not having a scrollpane for the tables. I didn't do that originally because it put a funky border around it and setting border to null did not work. What I had to do was set an empty border.